# Import from excel to sql format error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

hi I am trying to load data into sql from an excel spreadsheet from a web page, I am getting a  "Cannot implicitly convert type '`string`' to '`decimal`" error I have tried different ways to correct this but nothing is working.

```
namespace CarpartsStore.Dealers
{

partial class DealerHome : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelUpload.Visible = true;
        PanelView.Visible = false;
        PanelImport.Visible = false;
    }


    protected OleDbCommand ExcelConnection()
    {

        // Connect to the Excel Spreadsheet
        string xConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/ExcelImport.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        // create your excel connection object using the connection string
        OleDbConnection objXConn = new OleDbConnection(xConnStr);
        objXConn.Open();

        // use a SQL Select command to retrieve the data from the Excel Spreadsheet
        // the "table name" is the name of the worksheet within the spreadsheet
        // in this case, the worksheet name is "Members" and is coded as: [Members$]
        OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Products$]", objXConn);
        return objCommand;



    }

    protected void ButtonView_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelUpload.Visible = false;
        PanelView.Visible = true;
        PanelImport.Visible = false;

        // Create a new Adapter
        OleDbDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        // retrieve the Select command for the Spreadsheet
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = ExcelConnection();

        // Create a DataSet
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        // Populate the DataSet with the spreadsheet worksheet data
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

        // Bind the data to the GridView
        GridViewExcel.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridViewExcel.DataBind();
    }


    protected void ButtonImport_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelUpload.Visible = false;
        PanelView.Visible = false;
        PanelImport.Visible = true;
        LabelImport.Text = "";
        // reset to blank

        // retrieve the Select Command for the worksheet data
        OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        objCommand = ExcelConnection();

        //  create a DataReader
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();


        //  create variables for the spreadsheet columns
        int ProductID = 0;
        int MakeID = 0;
        int DealerID = 0;
        string PartNumber = "";
        string Description = "";
        decimal UnitCost = 0.00M;
        decimal Postage = 0.00M;
        int QtyAvailable = 0;
        string UserName = "";
        string Make = "";


        int counter = 0;
        // used for testing your import in smaller increments

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            // counter to exit early for testing...

            // set default values for loop
            ProductID = 0;
            MakeID = 0;
            DealerID = 0;



            PartNumber = GetValueFromReader(reader,"PartNumber");
            Description = GetValueFromReader(reader,"Description");


            UnitCost = GetValueFromReader(reader,"UnitCost");
            Postage = GetValueFromReader(reader, "Postage"); 


            QtyAvailable = GetValueFromReader(reader,"QtyAvailable");
            UserName = GetValueFromReader(reader,"UserName");
            Make = GetValueFromReader(reader,"Make");


            // Insert any required validations here...

            MakeID = GetMakeID(Make);
            DealerID = GetDealerID(UserName); 


            //retrieve the MakeID
            ProductID = ImportIntoProducts(PartNumber, Description, UnitCost, Postage, QtyAvailable, MakeID, DealerID);

            LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + ProductID + PartNumber + " " + Description + " " + UnitCost + " " + Postage + " " + QtyAvailable + " " + UserName + " Make_id: " + MakeID + " " + Make + "<br>";
            //If counter > 2 Then ' exit early for testing, comment later...
            //    Exit While
            //End If

        }
        reader.Close();

    }



    protected string GetValueFromReader(OleDbDataReader myreader, string stringValue)
    {
        object val = myreader[stringValue];
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
            return val.ToString();
        else
            return "";
    }


    protected void ButtonUploadFile_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUploadExcel.HasFile)
        {


            try
            {
                // alter path for your project

                FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelImport.xls"));
                LabelUpload.Text = "Upload File Name: " +
                    FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                    "Type: " + FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType +
                    " File Size: " + FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentLength +
                    " kb<br>";
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                LabelUpload.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LabelUpload.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
        }

    }



    protected int GetMakeID(string MakeName)
    {

        int makeID = 0;
        try
        {
            CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.MakesTableAdapter SSAdapter = new CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.MakesTableAdapter();
            SSSProductsDataSet.MakesDataTable SSDataTable = null;
            SSDataTable = SSAdapter.GetMakeByName(MakeName);
            // see if the category already exists in the table, if not insert it
            if (SSDataTable != null)
            {
                if (SSDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (SSDataTable[0].MakeID > 0)
                    {
                        makeID = SSDataTable[0].MakeID;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (makeID == 0)
            {
                // if it is still 0, then insert it into the table
                // retrieve the identity key category_id from the insert
                makeID = (int)SSAdapter.InsertMakeQuery(MakeName);
                // if this fails to return the proper category_id, make sure to 
                // set the InsertCategoryQuery ExecuteMode Property to Scalar
            }
            return makeID;
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + ex.Message;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    protected int GetDealerID(string UserName)
    {

        int DealerID = 0;
        try
        {
            CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.DealersTableAdapter SSAdapter = new CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.DealersTableAdapter();
            SSSProductsDataSet.DealersDataTable SSDataTable = null;
            SSDataTable = SSAdapter.GetDealersByUserName(UserName);
            // see if the User already exists in the table, if not insert it
            if (SSDataTable != null)
            {
                if (SSDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (SSDataTable[0].DealerID > 0)
                    {
                        DealerID = SSDataTable[0].DealerID;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (DealerID == 0)
            {
                // if it is still 0, then insert it into the table
                // retrieve the identity key category_id from the insert
                DealerID = 0;
                // if this fails to return the proper category_id, make sure to 
                // set the InsertCategoryQuery ExecuteMode Property to Scalar
            }
            return DealerID;
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + ex.Message;
            return 0;
        }

    }


    protected int ImportIntoProducts(string PartNumber, string Description, decimal UnitCost, decimal Postage, int QtyAvailable, int MakeID, int DealerID)
    {


        // make sure values don't exceed column limits
        PartNumber = Left(PartNumber, 50);
        Description = Left(Description, 300);
        UnitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(UnitCost);





        int ProductID = 0;
        try
        {
            CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter SSAdapter = new CarpartsStore.DataSets.SSSProductsDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();
            SSSProductsDataSet.ProductsDataTable SSDataTable = null;
            SSDataTable = SSAdapter.GetProductsByPartNumberDealer(PartNumber, DealerID);
            // see if the category already exists in the table, if not insert it
            if (SSDataTable != null)
            {
                if (SSDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (SSDataTable[0].ProductID > 0)
                    {
                        ProductID = SSDataTable[0].ProductID;
                        LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + "<font color=blue>PartNumber Found, Not Imported: " + " ID: " + ProductID + " " + PartNumber + " " + Description + "" + UnitCost + "" + Postage + ".</font><br>";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ProductID == 0)
            {
                // if it is still 0, then insert it into the table
                // retrieve the identity key ProductID from the insert
                ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(SSAdapter.InsertProductQuery(PartNumber, Description,UnitCost, Postage, QtyAvailable, MakeID, DealerID));
                LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + "<font color=white>Part Number Imported: " + " ID: " + ProductID + " " + PartNumber + " " + Description + " Cost: " + UnitCost + ".</font><br>";
            }
            return ProductID;
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text + "<font color=red>" + ex.Message      + "</font><br>";
            return 0;
        }

    }



    // http://www.mgbrown.com/PermaLink68.aspx
    public static string Left(string text, int length)
    {
        if (length < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", length, "length must be > 0");
        else if (length == 0 || text.Length == 0)
            return "";
        else if (text.Length <= length)
            return text;
        else
            return text.Substring(0, length);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: There's a _lot_ of code here.  Where do you get the error?  And what are the runtime values which produce the error?

Comment: You need debugging and see what's the data exactly is causing the exception, it might be the Excel data format is wrong, or maybe it's just an empty string, the exception message is already so detailed so without debugging I don't think you can figure it out.

Also if this is a one time stuff I highly recommend go ahead using SQL Server import tool to do the job

Comment: Hi the three lines causing the problem are these
                UnitCost = GetValueFromReader(reader,"UnitCost");
                Postage = GetValueFromReader(reader, "Postage"); 
                QtyAvailable = GetValueFromReader   (reader,"QtyAvailable");   the first two are decimals and last one is int, i have tried converting from string but this dosent work either

Answer (score 0):

The following code change will allow your code to run:

```
try
{
    UnitCost = GetValueFromReader(reader,"UnitCost");
}
catch(Exception)
{
   // put a breakpoint here to find the problem using the debugger
}

try
{
    Postage = GetValueFromReader(reader, "Postage"); 
}
catch(Exception)
{
   // put a breakpoint here to find the problem using the debugger
}
```

What you really want to do is understand how the source data is causing the error.  (Maybe you have a null or a non-numeric value in the source data.)

Leaving the code like this could (and probably will) introduce data errors into other parts of your system.